# Splitting the string and store it in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I want the following string to be stored into an array but it throws ArrayOutOfBound Exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    char[] arr = {};
    String str = "Hello My Name is Ivkaran";
    for (int i = 0;i < str.length(); i++){
        System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
        arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared an array of length 0 with this line:

```
char[] arr = {};
```

To assign anything to that array, it must be initialized to some non-zero size.  Here, it looks like you need it to be the same size as the string.

```
String str = "Hello My Name is Ivkaran";
char[] arr = new char[str.length()];
```

You can also just call [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) on the `String` to get a `char[]` with the contents copied into it already.

```
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
```

Comment: You don't have to create a new array first. Check my answer.

Comment: @ataravati That's true.  Check my answer.  I had included `toCharArray()` in it already.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not dynamic in Java. Either use an arraylist or create the array with a dimention as:

```
char[] arr = new char[str.length()]
```

Also move this line below the

```
String str = "Hello My Name is Ivkaran";
```

Then continue as originally.

Comment: You are not converting the string to an array here. You are just creating a new empty array with the length of the string.

Comment: @ataravati: you can't "convert" any string to an array then according to your interpretation, unless you destroy the string object and overwrite its address space with an array. What hexafraction suggests will essentially "convert" the string to an array.

Comment: You know what I meant. And, you edited your answer already. But, you don't need to loop through the characters in the string. Check my answer. There's already a method for that.

Comment: I don't know what you meant, there's no "conversion" in your answer either. That would assume the original value is replaced by the new one, while both still exist in your case. I'm aware you don't need a loop, but this looks like an exercise on using one.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
String str = "Hello My Name is Ivkaran"; 
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
```